# Facebook login not working Parse

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm trying to integrate Facebook login function to my app.

When I click on "continue with Facebook button" everything works but the user info is not added to the parse database also the "logs" when login success or failure also not appearing in the logcat.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends Activity {

LoginButton loginButtonFB;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

    final List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("public_profile");
        add("email");
    }};


    loginButtonFB = findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);

    loginButtonFB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(FacebookLoginActivity.this, mPermissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(final ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                    if (parseUser == null) {

                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");

                    } else if (parseUser.isNew()) {

                        if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(parseUser)) {
                            ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(parseUser, FacebookLoginActivity.this, mPermissions, new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException ex) {
                                    if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(parseUser)) {
                                        Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");

                                        Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, "Logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(parseUser)) {
                            ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(parseUser, FacebookLoginActivity.this, mPermissions, new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException ex) {
                                    if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(parseUser)) {
                                        Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
                                        Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, "Logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: why the parse.com tag? parse.com does not exist (anymore)...you do know that parse was shut down a while ago, right?

Answer (score 0):

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        initialiseControls();

```
 private void initialiseControls(){
    txtStatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    login_button=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
}

private void loginWithFb(){
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGGED IN USING FACEBOOK !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //txtStatus.setText("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!!!\n" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Intent testactivty = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VenuesActivity.class);
            startActivity(testactivty);
            updateUI(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAILED !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

It works for me...Hope it helps you